# How to add marker while click on geosearch location?

Tags: arcgis-10.1

I am using the archgis map and basemap street.1) Fist i click on the geosearch button and then show the search location when i click on the search location one function fire which is shown below:

function chooseAddr(latt,longt)

{
$('#linkid').attr('data-latt', '');
var combine=latt+','+longt;
$('#linkid').attr('data-latt', combine);
 $('#linkid').click();
 //abc();
}

This is written on index.html page and on js file

```
$("#linkid").on("click",    function() {
    alert('inside the abc');

    var dataLatt = $('#linkid')=='undefined'||$('#linkid')==''?'0,0':$('#linkid').data('latt');
    var splitdata = dataLatt.split(",");
    var latt = splitdata[0];
    var longt = splitdata[1];
    addmarker(latt, longt);

    //addmarker('28.833333', '76.666667');

});
function addmarker(latt, longtt) {

    polygraphlayer.clear();

    var pt1 = new Point(Number(longtt), Number(latt));

    var markersymbol1 = new PictureMarkerSymbol('images/marker.png', 10, 15);

    polygraphlayer.add( Graphic(pt1, markersymbol1));

     //map.add(polygraphlayer);

    //map.graphics.add(polygraphlayer);


}
```

Its show the marker first time next time when i click on the search with different lat, long marker is not shown with same functions